# Streaming-based pipe with common state

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I'm Haskell beginner and newbie in **Streaming** library (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) as fastest and (I'm hope) simplest stream library. I'm trying to make next common and popular "pattern": processing of stream items with common state, see Fig, please:

```
   .--state-------+--state'--------+--state''-->
   |              |                |
[e0..eN] ==> [e0'...eN'] ==> [e0''..eN''] =====>
```

This "state" will be used for statistics, errors, whatever - through the whole workflow. Some of "pipe" nodes will iterate over `eN` items (which will be lists/streams too), concatenates results... How this can be achieved with Streaming library? I mean each "node" should have access to stream items but to "global" state too. Also nodes will do IO actions! I tried to use return of "node" as state (second component in Stream's pair): stream is monad, so `do e <- stream` binds one of returning values to `e`, but this does not look very rightly...

One of my attempts is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S


type R = Writer [String] ()

gen :: S.Stream (S.Of Int) IO R
gen = do
  S.yield 1000
  S.yield 2000
  -- lift $ putStr "enter x: " -- ERROR: shown after input!!!
  x <- lift getLine
  let n = read x::Int
  S.yield n
  return $ do
    tell ["genErr1"]
    tell ["genErr2"]

proc1 :: S.Stream (S.Of Int) IO R -> S.Stream (S.Of Int) IO R
proc1 str = loop str
  where
    loop str = do
      e <- lift $ S.next str
      e' <- case e of
        Left err -> return err
        Right (e', str') -> (S.yield $ e' + 123) >> loop str'
      return $ do
        tell ["proc1Err1"]
        tell ["proc1Err2"]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  p <- S.mapM_ print $ proc1 gen
  putStr "p: " >> print p
```

where I use "Write"-monad as return value (to save there my logs/statistics)...

So, I want to process with `proc1` stream items getting from `gen` and to have at the end some state global for all pipe where will be "genErr1", "genErr2", "proc1Err1", "proc1Err2" (they simulate errors occuring while process stream's items). How to achieve this? Could somebody help me, please?

PS. Interesting error: print happens after input (marked as ERROR in code).

Comment: Minor note: the output-after-input is usually caused by buffering. Try to either end with a newline (`putStrLn`) or expicitly `hFlush stdin` after the print.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want, you can add state to stream with a `StateT` transformer like this: `Stream (Of Elem) (StateT State IO) Result`.

Comment: @chi: oh, right! Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying with WriterT: `type W = WriterT [String] IO` and now `gen::S.Stream (S.Of Int) W ()`. It calls `lift $ tell ["err1"]`, but `proc1` calls `tell` in loop so I get multiple same messages in Writer's monoid. I don't know how to do it only once... But your suggestions is right, yes.

Comment: @freestyle: thanks! It works. Is such solution good/convenient from performance point of view?

Comment: @Paul-AG: Well, I don't know a better solution except to write the library of streams with state. So, this solution will be with some overhead, but this price for reusing the code.

Comment: Further to freestyle's response, see the Streaming function `distribute` to get a Stream into shape for calling `evalStateT`.